# Explaining a change in job-type due to an injury to potential employers

Tags: interviewing

A couple months ago I started work at a small farm, but injured myself on the job. It was under the table work, so there's no worker's comp or anything, and we agreed that I had to stop working. The doctor says it could be another few months before my knee is fully rehabbed. I have a little savings to fall back on, but I'll need a (non-labor-intensive) job to see me through until the start of next season (almost a year from now). The trouble is that my resume only looks good for farm work or landscaping.

How can I explain the change in the type of work I'll be doing to potential employers to minimize the chance they will reject me off-hand? I'm not changing careers away from farm work, and I don't see myself still working at this other less-labor-intensive job next year. I mean, telling them about my knee seems bad for my prospects, but I don't know how to answer those questions without telling them about my knee.

Comment: Is seasonal work an option? In retail a lot of cashiers go on vacation, a job you can easily learn in 1 day.

Comment: Hey user, and welcome to [workplace.se]! Right now you have the core of a good question, but there are a lot of parts of your question which aren't a great fit with the guidelines in our [help]. I am going to [edit] your question to try to make it a good fit, but if you think I screwed it up, please feel free to make an [edit] of your own to fix it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question "How can I explain the change in type of work to potential employers to minimize the chance they will reject me off-hand?" is incoherent. "change in type of work" to what type of work? What type of work were you performing under the table to begin with? Does the "change in type of work" refer to non-farm work that are planning to perform because you injured your knee followed by farm work that you are planning to perform after your knee heals? I am flagging your question as unclear.

Comment: Do you think *not* telling them that you have every intention to leave in a year is fair to them? Extending Ajaxkevi's comment - jobs requiring very little training could be an option, and telling them that you're leaving in a year shouldn't do too much to your chances.

Comment: Hey user, would you mind taking a look at the edits I made and clarify further? I made some assumptions based on what I *think* you're asking. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell them about your knee injury without telling them that it happened at undocumented work. Your "objective" (whether a section on your resume or a paragraph in your cover letter) should mention it, in fact:

> Seeking a [whatever you're applying for] position that uses my intensive knowledge of farming and landscaping, along with my superior [you-tell-me] skills, for [6 months, a year, whatever] while I recover from a knee injury.

If you think you wouldn't be hired if they knew it was temporary, then:

> Seeking a [whatever you're applying for] position that uses my intensive knowledge of farming and landscaping, along with my superior [you-tell-me] skills and does not aggravate my existing knee injury.

In the interview, when asked "why do you want this job?" you can reply

> I love farming and landscaping, but can't do it for at least [6 months] while my knee fully heals. I can get around fine, walking and living my daily life, but I can't do a lot of strenuous activity. So I'm looking for something a little less strenuous that still uses my particular skills. [Launch into what those are.]

Again, if you don't want to come clean about the temporary nature:

> I love farming and landscaping, but can't do it since I hurt my knee. I can get around fine, walking and living my daily life, but I can't do a lot of strenuous activity. So I'm looking for something a little less strenuous that still uses my particular skills. [Launch into what those are.]

A smart employer will see (if you write it for them) a chance to take advantage of an opportunity to get someone who's not normally available for this kind of thing. For example, if you worked in a garden centre or at a farm supply store, that would not be as strenuous, but you'd bring a ton of experience to the picture. Try to find employers to whom both your previous background and the fact that farming's not an option right now are advantages, and make sure you tell them about that.

If someone asks such a personal question as "how did you hurt your knee?" you can just decline to answer. It just isn't relevant to a job interview.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't lie to them.

After all, employment is a bargain, they get a worker who can do a fine job in a non-labor situation for a year for what they pay. A year is a perfectly acceptable duration of employment for a job that does not require extensive training.

Just be honest, tell them about your knee injury, utilize your old boss from the farm as a positive reference if you need a reference (that you're honest and hard working).

The fact you have a clear motive to switch careers can really help with your employment history. It makes the change of careers a lot more understandable. I would not hide any details that show legitimate motivation from my resume if I were you.